# Subset of colorbrewer set in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, colorbrewer

I'd like to use only the 5 darkest colors from the 'Blues' color set from colorbrewer.js. How do I do that? I can't find any documentation covering it. Here's my code:

```
var colorScale = d3.scale.quantize()
    .domain([0, maxInteractions*2])
    .range(colorbrewer.Blues[9]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`colorbrewer.Blues[9]` is just an array of colors. You can use good old `array.slice()` to get the last five elements.

```
colorbrewer.Blues[9]
//["#f7fbff", "#deebf7", "#c6dbef", "#9ecae1", "#6baed6", "#4292c6", "#2171b5", "#08519c", "#08306b"]

colorbrewer.Blues[9].slice(4)
//["#6baed6", "#4292c6", "#2171b5", "#08519c", "#08306b"]
```